# how to add watermark to pdf using itexpdf

Tags: java, itextpdf

i am using following code to generate pdf file, everything is fine and working but i need to add watermark with the pdf file also alternate color to rows generated in pdf table.

```
response.setHeader("Content-disposition", "attachment; filename=\"" + reportName + ".pdf\"");
        response.setContentType("application/pdf");
        PdfWriter.getInstance(document,response.getOutputStream());

        try {
            document.open();
            addTitlePage(document, reportName,path);

           /* Image image = Image.getInstance(path+"images/abi.png");
            image.setAbsolutePosition(40f, 770f);
            image.scaleAbsolute(70f, 50f);
            document.add(image);*/

            //float[] colsWidth = {1.5f,3f,4f,4f,2f};

            List<Float> colsWidth = new ArrayList<Float>();
            int iterator = 1;
           while (iterator <= headerMap.size()) {
               if(iterator==1){
                   colsWidth.add(1.5f); 
               }else{
                colsWidth.add(3f); 
               }
                iterator++;
            }
           float[] floatArray = ArrayUtils.toPrimitive(colsWidth.toArray(new Float[0]), 0.0F);

           PdfPTable table = new PdfPTable(floatArray);
            table.setWidthPercentage(98);
            table.setHorizontalAlignment(Element.ALIGN_CENTER);

            PdfPCell c1 = new PdfPCell();
            for (Iterator it = headerMap.keySet().iterator(); it.hasNext();) {
                String headerName = (String) headerMap.get(it.next());
                c1 = new PdfPCell(new Phrase(headerName, headerFont));
                c1.setBackgroundColor(BaseColor.LIGHT_GRAY);
                table.addCell(c1);
            }
            table.setHeaderRows(1);
            table = custDAO.creadPDFTable(query, table);
            document.add(table);
            document.addAuthor(userViewModel.getUsername());
            document.addCreationDate();
            document.addCreator("POC");
            document.close();
            response.flushBuffer();
private static void addTitlePage(Document document, String reportName,String path) throws DocumentException, MalformedURLException, IOException {
        Paragraph preface = new Paragraph();
        addEmptyLine(preface, 1);
        /**
         * Lets write a big header
         */
        Paragraph paragraph = new Paragraph(reportName, titleFont);
        paragraph.setAlignment(Element.ALIGN_CENTER);
        document.add(paragraph);

        /**
         * Add one empty line
         */
        addEmptyLine(preface, 1);
        document.add(preface);
        Image image = Image.getInstance(path+"/"+"/abilogo.PNG");
        image.setAbsolutePosition(40f, 770f);
        image.scaleAbsolute(70f, 50f);
        document.add(image);

    }
    private static void addEmptyLine(Paragraph paragraph, int number) {
        for (int i = 0; i < number; i++) {
            paragraph.add(new Paragraph(" "));
        }
    }
```

and this the method i use to create `pdftable.(rows)`

```
public PdfPTable creadPDFTable(String query,PdfPTable table){
        int numberOfColumns=0,sno=1;
        Connection connection = getConnection();
        if (connection != null) {
            try {
                PreparedStatement reportTablePS = connection.prepareStatement(query);
                ResultSet reportTable_rst = reportTablePS.executeQuery();
                ResultSetMetaData reportTable_rsmd = reportTable_rst.getMetaData();
                numberOfColumns = reportTable_rsmd.getColumnCount();
                while (reportTable_rst.next()) {
                    table.addCell(new PdfPCell(new Paragraph(String.valueOf(sno), textFont)));
                            for (int columnIterator = 1; columnIterator <= numberOfColumns; columnIterator++) {
                                 String column = reportTable_rst.getString(columnIterator);
                                 table.addCell(new PdfPCell(new Paragraph(column, textFont)));
                            }
                            sno++;
            }
            } catch (Exception ex) {
                ex.printStackTrace();
            }finally {
                try {
                    closeConnection(connection, null, null);
                } catch (Exception ex) {
                    ex.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
        }
        return table;
    }
```

my main concern is to add watermark also adding alternate color to rows.

Please help to resolve this as i am unable to fix this for long time.

Regards

Answer (score 1):

If you want add an watermark as a image u can use the code below. An other way to add a text watermark is to use annotations.

```
PdfReader pdfReader = null;
    Stream outputStream = null;
    PdfStamper pdfStamper = null;

    try
    {
        pdfReader = GetPdfReaderObject();
        outputStream = new FileStream(filePathDestination, FileMode.Create, FileAccess.Write, FileShare.None);
        pdfStamper = new PdfStamper(pdfReader, outputStream);

            PdfLayer layer = new PdfLayer("watermark", pdfStamper.Writer);

            for (int pageIndex = 1; pageIndex <= pdfReader.NumberOfPages; pageIndex++) {
                pdfStamper.FormFlattening = false;
                iTextSharp.text.Rectangle pageRectangle = pdfReader.GetPageSizeWithRotation(pageIndex);
                PdfContentByte pdfData = pdfStamper.GetOverContent(pageIndex);

                pdfData.BeginLayer(layer);

                PdfGState graphicsState = new PdfGState();
                graphicsState.FillOpacity = 0.5F;
                pdfData.SetGState(graphicsState);
                pdfData.BeginText();

                iTextSharp.text.Image watermarkImage = iTextSharp.text.Image.GetInstance(System.Drawing.Image.FromFile(watermarkImagePath), ImageFormat.Png);

                float width = pageRectangle.Width;
                float height = pageRectangle.Height;

                watermarkImage.SetAbsolutePosition(width / 2 - watermarkImage.Width / 2, height / 2 - watermarkImage.Height / 2);

                pdfData.AddImage(watermarkImage);
                pdfData.EndText();
                pdfData.EndLayer();
            }
        }
        pdfStamper.Close();
        outputStream.Close();
        outputStream.Dispose();
        pdfReader.Close();
        pdfReader.Dispose();

    } catch (Exception e) {
        ....
    }
}
```

And not forget to remove the watermark if you want to add an other watermark.